# Prevent the EXIT of a kivy App on Android with the ESCAPE ARROW

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to prevent the EXIT of a kivy App on Android with the ESCAPE ARROW.

When I write `exit_on_escape = 0` in the `config.ini` file, it does not change anything (however on WINDOWS 8 with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key this works).

I have also tried unsuccessfully to intercept the `on_request_close`.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.8')

from kivy.core.window import WindowBase
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock

class Test(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test,self).__init__(**kwargs)     

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):

    Clock.schedule_once(self.my_callback, 0)
    return Test()

def my_callback(self,*dt):
    print("mycallback")
    win=self._app_window
    win.fullscreen=1 #OK 
    win.bind(on_request_close=self.alwaystrue)

def alwaystrue(*largs, **kwargs) :
    print("alwaystrue")#never happens ...
    return True
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the following code snippet just below the `import kivy` statement

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'exit_on_escape', '0')
```

Comment: **This is the way.** With Kivy, it's inscrutable incantations of doom all the way down.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this in your App class:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.bind(on_start=self.post_build_init)
        # do all your normal stuff as well
        return whatever

    def post_build_init(self,ev):
        if platform() == 'android':
            import android
            android.map_key(android.KEYCODE_BACK, 1001)

        win = Window
        win.bind(on_keyboard=self.key_handler)

    def key_handler(self, window, keycode1, keycode2, text, modifiers):
        if keycode1 == 27 or keycode1 == 1001:
            # Do whatever you want here - or nothing at all
            # Returning True will eat the keypress
            return True
        return False
```

This is probably not all be necessary (using the intermediate `post_build_init()` method and the `android.map_key()` thing), but I originally got it from a mailing post and I don't think I have an updated version. Anyway, it works for me.

Comment: `android.map_key(android.KEYCODE_BACK, 1001)` is no longer required in 2023 and is, in fact, harmful. Doing so conflicts with standard input widgets like `TextInput`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example, how to use on_request_close.

The line:

```
Config.set('kivy', 'exit_on_escape', '0')
```

disables the Esc -button.

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'exit_on_escape', '0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window


class ChildApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.bind(on_request_close=self.on_request_close)
        return Label(text='Child')

    def on_request_close(self, *args):
        self.textpopup(title='Exit', text='Are you sure?')
        return True

    def textpopup(self, title='', text=''):
        """Open the pop-up with the name.

        :param title: title of the pop-up to open
        :type title: str
        :param text: main text of the pop-up to open
        :type text: str
        :rtype: None
        """
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        box.add_widget(Label(text=text))
        mybutton = Button(text='OK', size_hint=(1, 0.25))
        box.add_widget(mybutton)
        popup = Popup(title=title, content=box, size_hint=(None, None), size=(600, 300))
        mybutton.bind(on_release=self.stop)
        popup.open()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ChildApp().run()
```